# How to verify LD_PRELOAD is running?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I know that `LD_PRELOAD` is set my so library before any another so libraries.

`LD_PRELOAD=my_lib.so ./my_exec`

How can I watch it? Is there any path like `/proc/pid/...` that show the order of libraries that loaded  for this process?

Comment: Perhaps you could override some random function like `open` and make it crash the program. Then run it. Does the program crash?

Answer (score 2):

Look in `/proc/$pid/maps`, you should see the library there if it's loaded. As for checking the order of loading, the "before" part is by definition, to quote the man page:

> LD_PRELOAD
>
> A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared objects to be loaded before all others.

Comment: So I need to see into `/proc/$pid/maps` the library `my_lib.so` in lower address than another library?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think the current loader will assign random addresses to libraries, because security. Why do you care? If it is loaded, any public symbols in your library will override the symbols with the same name in libraries that would normally be loaded. That's what preloading does.

Comment: I suspect an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you actually trying to solve?